# vim - maintain a session in shell by executing commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vim, vim-plugin

vim has a number of ways to execute shell commands from within vim. One can jump to the shell and back to vim using `shell`, `ctrl+z` the current process and get back using `fg`. Selected/Current lines can be executed using `!w bash`.

However, all these approaches are helpful only for running one command. Once the command executes, the shell is process is killed.

I wanted to know if there is a way to keep executing snippets of code in the shell and have the shell remember functions/variables from the previous command (similar to copying snippets of code to a shell prompt) to debug code. For this the shell session would have to be persisted somehow.

I often run into cases where I need to execute a few functions on the shell and then test them out by calling them. The standard approach would be to copy paste them in a different shell and then execute them. How to do this from within vim?

Comment: try vimshell plugin,  https://github.com/Shougo/vimshell.vim

Comment: Another approach is to use a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen` to allow a "split" terminal window with `vim` in one half and a shell session in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Vim was build with Python support (most Unix builds are, Windows / Cygwin builds are not), you might want to have a look at the [Conque Shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) plugin, which allows to run a shell [inside a Vim buffer](http://conque.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/screenshot/unix.jpg).

**Edit:** Correction, apparently Vim 7.3 for Windows now also comes with Python support (and thus, Conque compatibility).

Comment: I was also looking for something like that. Would you help me with the set up this with Gvim ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I don't use it myself, I just remembered the link. The installation instructions seem to be pretty straightforward. If you encounter problems, just post a question on SuperUser. I'm sure you'll get help. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could start vim (not gvim) from a shell, then use `<C-Z>` to suspend vim.  You return to the calling shell (not a sub-shell) and resume vim with `fg`.  According to the docs, this works "On many Unix systems".

```
:help suspend
```